# Android listview shows elements at the bottom when there is few elements?

Tags: android, listview

When the size of elements is few,like 1,2 or 3 in a Listview
It shows elements at the bottom.How can I make it to show elements at the top even there are few? Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lavgf.png).

Here's my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="4px" 
        android:paddingBottom="4px"
        android:background="@drawable/fbbar"
        android:layout_height="50dip">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/searchText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:hint="type to search..." 
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_text"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_contacts_refresh"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/refresh"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/contactsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" 
        android:background="#fff" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1px" android:divider="#777a"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="2dip" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@drawable/fbbar"> 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's weird as hell. I have no idea, this all looks good. Try for the `ListView`: `android:layout_gravity="top"`. I have no idea if that will help, but who knows?

Answer (score 0):

i think you problem is here android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"

Comment: actually I found the bug was in the java side sorry

Comment: Can you explain the error? I'm interested because I'm getting the same situation.